# scrapy items to xampp mysql database

Tags: python, scrapy

I know this question was asked many times but it never seems to be solved anywhere. I looked in several threads and tried all suggestions without success.

The question is: why is nothing stored into my local database?

I am scraping a website, follow 2 links on each site to scrape more data.
What i already successfully checked is:

- if i can print items from my spider.class
- if my xpath is correct
- if i can print inside my pipeline.class
- if my pipeline is included
- if queries work

**mySpider.py**

```
import scrapy
from mySpider.items import myItems

class bandSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "info"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [ 'http://example.com' ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        item = myItems()
        item['id']          =   response.xpath('//h1/a/@href').re_first(r'\d+')
        item['name']       =   response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract_first()
        item['logo']       =   response.xpath('//a[@id="logo"]/@href').extract()
        item['img']        =   response.xpath('//a[@id="photo"]/@href').extract()

        yield item

        # follow link
        yield scrapy.Request('https://example.com/page1' + response.xpath('//h1/a/@href').re_first(r'\d+'), callback=self.parse_page1)
        yield scrapy.Request('https://example.com/page2', callback=self.parse_page2)



    def parse_page1(self, response):
        item = myItems()
        item['comment']    =   response.xpath('//body//text()').extract()
        yield item

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        item = myItems()
        item['another']      =   response.css('a.link ::text').extract()
        yield item
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import scrapy
import pymysql

class MyspiderPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='mydb', charset='utf8')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.conn.autocommit(True)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        for i in range(5):
            try:
                self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `tablename` ( `id`, `name` , `logo` , `img` , `comment` )
                                VALUES ( %s , %s , %s , %s , %s )  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = name, logo = logo, img = img, comment = comment""",(item['id'].encode('utf-8'), item["name"].encode('utf-8'), item["logo".encode('utf-8')], item["img"].encode('utf-8'), item["comment"].encode('utf-8')))

            except:
                continue
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class bandinfo(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    id = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    logo = scrapy.Field()
    img = scrapy.Field()
    comment = scrapy.Field()
    another = scrapy.Field()

    return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()
```

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'mySpider'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['mySpider.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'mySpider.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

COOKIES_ENABLED = False

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'mySpider.pipelines.MyspiderPipeline': 300,
}
```

**console output**

```
PS \scrapy\mySpider> scrapy crawl info
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: mySpider)
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'mySpider', 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'mySpider.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['mySpider.spiders']}
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['mySpider.pipelines.MyspiderPipeline']
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-09-14 11:29:55 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-09-14 11:29:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-09-14 11:29:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com> (referer: None)
2017-09-14 11:29:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://example.com/img.jpeg>
{'img': ['https://example.com/img.jpeg'],
 'logo': ['https://example.com/logo.jpeg'],
 'name': 'any name',
 'id': '546',
2017-09-14 11:29:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/page1> (referer: https://example.com )
2017-09-14 11:29:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://example.com/page1>
{'comment': ['tons of text'}
2017-09-14 11:29:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.com/page2> (referer: https://example.com )
2017-09-14 11:29:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://example.com/page2>
{'another': ['tons of text']}
2017-09-14 11:29:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-09-14 11:29:57 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1101,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 10979,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 14, 9, 29, 57, 981309),
 'item_scraped_count': 3,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 14, 9, 29, 55, 590397)}
2017-09-14 11:29:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

What i see in the output is:

```
Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

I also tried to search for this issue but i can't find any solution.
Is anything missing? It just seems many people have the same problems and it is never solved.

Comment: No one has any clue what could be wrong?
This issue is sadly never solved.

I guess there is just one detail what is wrong. I hope anybode can help

Comment: Upgrade to latest scrapy just to make sure its is not an already resolved issue. `pip install scrapy --force --update`. Also when do you have `close_spider` in the items.py? Also whey you are masking issues using `except: continue`. You should catch the exception and print the issue. If you need to find issues then such code should not be there

Comment: You should write this as an answer. The hint to write a real exception helped me to solve the problem. It was just a mistake in my sql queries.
Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to latest scrapy just to make sure its is not an already resolved issue.

```
pip install scrapy --force --update
```

why do you have close_spider in the items.py?

Why you are masking issues using `except:` and  `continue`?

You should catch the exception and print the issue. The exception will tell if the query is failing or not